# Is $f$ a function? If so find the domain and image

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Is $f$ a function? If so find the domain and image.

$$f= \{(x,y): x,y \text{are natural numbers (not including 0)}, x|y \text{ and }y|x\} $$

My thoughts below

> I thought that $x|y$ and $y|x$ would imply that $x=y$, is this correct, if
>   so, then does this imply that:
>       Domain: all natural numbers
>       Imf: all natural numbers

$$f= \{(x,y): x,y\text{ are integer numbers, }x|y\text{ and }y|x\}$$

My thoughts below:

> This isn't a function: let $x=2$, then $x|2 $ and $x|-2$ , so there are two
>   such $y$ that $x=2$ maps to, namely $y=2$ and $y=-2$

Is this correct?

Comment: Your reasoning seems good to me.  The first is the identity function.  The second is not a function but the relationship |x| = |y|